# Connect form web part to DVWP to allow searching

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, data-form-web-part

Have an .aspx page with a DVWP that is connected to a list containing 700+ records. I would like to drop a search on this page (HTML Form webpart?) to allow keyword/freeform search criteria that would search and retrieve results from the DVWP.

I'm not a hardcore developer so a no code solution would be great. I've created connections to RSS feeds to populate a DG, but this starts with an empty DG and searches an external site, then returns results to the DG.

Can this be done in the same fashion? How?

Comment: You could use filter web parts connected to the DVWP. What's a DG?

Comment: DG=Datagrid. I am using filtering now, however, field level searching is required. Fields contain memo type comments so I need to search for keywords.